# Domain Driven Design query between aggregates

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

Im new in DDD and I would like yours advise.
In my UI I need to view data from 2 aggregates.Im using EF Core and as I have read its better to keep only one navigation between entities so not to mix two aggregates and avoids serialization issues due to circular references.
How should I make the query?
Do I need to create a new view whenever I need data from 2 aggregates?
If needs to create views in which layer this view can exist? In infrastructure persistance layer or domain?

Thank you

Comment: Too many, too broad questions in one post.

Comment: Maybe but are relatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I make the query?

With the simplest and fastest technology you can use. I mean: if building the query with EF Core requires several steps and a lot of extra objects, change approach and try with a direct SQL request. It's query, something you can test fast and you can change equally fast, whenever you need to do.

> Do I need to create a new view whenever I need data from 2 aggregates?

You don't. With a view you hide away (in the view) the complexity oft the data read (at the code to change the DB every time the data to show should change), with the illusion/feeling that you manage an entity. Or course it should be clear that the data comes from a view. A query, on the other side, is more code related (to change the data shown you just change the query), but you also show "directly" that that data come from several sources.

***Note***: I've used EF Core years ago, and for a a really simple project. If with *view* you mean instead a view of the EF Core, than I would say yes. But only if building it doesn't require several steps/joins to gather the information. I would always think about a direct approach, when it looks that the code starts to be a bit too complex to show some data.

Here, anyway, the things can go really deep: do you have all your entities (root) in the same project? Or you have several microservices? With microservices, how do you share the data and how do you store it? Maybe a query is not viable, or it reads partially old data. As you can see, there're several thing to take into account when you have to read the data.

> If needs to create views in which layer this view can exist? In infrastructure persistance layer or domain?

As stated before, if you mean a view within the EF Core, I would put really close to the layer where you're going to use it. But, it could depend. You could have a look [here](https://herbertograca.com/2017/11/16/explicit-architecture-01-ddd-hexagonal-onion-clean-cqrs-how-i-put-it-all-together/).

Personally I use 3 layers: domain, application and infrastructure. My views are in the application layer, because I have several queries that I reuse for different purposes. But before going into the infrastructure (where the requests are) I transform the results into the format required for UI.

---

DDD is about putting together all the business logic that otherwise is spread around several entities, services and even controllers. With this solution, all the actions that the domain offers could be performed without requiring extra logic outside the domain itself. Of course you need to implement the services that the domain is going to use, this is obvious.

On the other side is clear, at least for me, that the reuse is limited to the domain itself. I mean:

- I can build a big query, that collects a lot of information from different sources, and reuse it for several UI views, but I've to be ready to pay the price of something that I have to touch every time something in the UI changes (anyway I need to transform this into a view related object);
- I can build small, specialized queries that I use for 1, 2 (if they are the same) UI views, paying the price of more code (but simple and  specialized, and really fast to test!) to maintain (here the query can produce close to/equal to view related object).

The second approach is the basic of CQRS, and I prefer that one. Remember, you can do CQRS even without event store and eventually consistency: you just take part of it, not the whole. We design to simplify our lives, not to make them harder.

Comment: thank you for your answer! First of all my mistake yes I mean a view in Ef core(SQL view) not a view in MVC. I have all my entities in one project and these 2 aggregates are in same bounded context. My problem is that when the user needs to make a search I need to show data from both of them. I can't make two call in aggregates to get the data and fill a view model with these because I need to return IQueryable as the components that I use in my UI needs IQueryable

Comment: yes it was useful did you saw my last comment?

Comment: Ok. Then I would say you to use a query, or a view (within the EF Core), that then you'll use to show the data. And, yes, I would create a view/query for each section of UI that is going to take information from several aggregates. The point, with DDD, is to reuse the domain business logic and put it a place (not spread it around several entities, services and controllers). But, about the visualization, at least for me, it looks clear that you should reuse if and only if the same data is shown, otherwise you create a new view block for each part of the UI.